# How to access to the website that doesn't provide and API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create an iphone application that can send value on the text field to the website page such as a comment. When I click submit my comment, the comment will show on the website. The website doesn't provide an API and it is not my website. Can i do that? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Well make sure they allow you to do so, and then use firebug or similar tools to get the HTTP request and response details, then simulate it on your app.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of websites will prevent you from sending POST or GET data from an external source as a security measure - so it's usually not going to be as simple as that.

It's probably not a feasible idea unless you can gain access to the website, and you say it's not your website. If you did have access to the website, or an agreement to upload a web service on their site, it would be a very simple matter.

Comment: Thanks for you post but how do i know that the website prevent sending POST and GET from external source. I can make an login form and submit value from my application and then i get the responseString the same as the website result page, is that mean it's not prevent sending POST and GET from the external source?

Comment: It's a good sign, although the process of figuring out how to actually get anything useful done may not be a simple one. Also realize that when they upgrade the website, there's a good chance your app won't work. I'd recommend trying to get in contact with the website owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the form with the same input fields and submit to the same form handler. No API is required to submit a form.